# How to build Megazine Front Page without any Plugin?

Tags: wordpress

Hey i've new [site](http://www.bollyera.com/) on bollywood topic, i've tried too many themes but i am not getting my desired page, so please suggest me best plugin for fornt page builder or anyother script

Answer (score -1):

[Visual composer](https://vc.wpbakery.com/) is the best plugin for the page builder Plugin.